# Asset validation error on App Store upload

Tags: upload, app-store, push

Asset validation failed
Invalid bundle structure. The “Fort.app/Pods/AppCenter/AppCenter-SDK-Apple/AppCenterAnalytics.xcframework/macos-arm64_x86_64/AppCenterAnalytics.framework/AppCenterAnalytics” binary file is not permitted. Your app cannot contain standalone executables or libraries, other than a valid CFBundleExecutable of supported bundles. For details, visit: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/placing_content_in_a_bundle (ID: 0a63d8d2-32ae-4c94-8bdb-b798a94cd4c8)